# PHP on a windows machine; Start process in background

Tags: php, windows, background, kill, nohup

I'm looking for the best, or any way really to start a process from php in the background so I can kill it later in the script.

Right now, I'm using: shell_exec($Command);
The problem with this is it waits for the program to close.

I want something that will have the same effect as nohup when I execute the shell command. This will allow me to run the process in the background, so that later in the script it can be closed. I need to close it because this script will run on a regular basis and the program can't be open when this runs.

I've thought of generating a .bat file to run the command in the background, but even then, how do I kill the process later?

The code I've seen for linux is:

```
$PID = shell_exec("nohup $Command > /dev/null & echo $!");
// Later on to kill it
exec("kill -KILL $PID");
```

**EDIT**: Turns out I don't need to kill the process

Comment: So what was the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will this [function from the PHP Manual](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#90664) help?

```
function runAsynchronously($path,$arguments) {
    $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
    $oShellLink = $WshShell->CreateShortcut("temp.lnk");
    $oShellLink->TargetPath = $path;
    $oShellLink->Arguments = $arguments;
    $oShellLink->WorkingDirectory = dirname($path);
    $oShellLink->WindowStyle = 1;
    $oShellLink->Save();
    $oExec = $WshShell->Run("temp.lnk", 7, false);
    unset($WshShell,$oShellLink,$oExec);
    unlink("temp.lnk");
}
```

Comment: I ended up using (almost) this to launch a batch file and it works perfectly now.

Comment: Sorry for digging out this old grave. I m using same code to execute external program i made in C#. The browser/php script or apache just hangs, if this c# application throws an exception. Is there any work around for this??

Answer (score 11):

`shell_exec('start /B "C:\Path\to\program.exe"');`

The `/B` parameter is key here.

I can't seem to find where I found this anymore. But this works for me.

Comment: For sake of completeness, I leave the link to the docs about the start command here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: this is wrong answer, it run without window not run in background, php will wait until the command finished. instead use `pclose(popen($command, 'r'));`

Answer (score 3):

Tried to achieve the same on a Windows 2000 server with PHP 5.2.8.

None of the solutions worked for me. PHP kept waiting for the response.

Found the solution to be :

```
$cmd = "E:\PHP_folder_path\php.exe E:\some_folder_path\backgroundProcess.php";
pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "a"));  // mode = "a" since I had some logs to edit
```

Answer (score 1):

From the php manual for `exec`:

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

ie pipe the output into a file and php won't wait for it:

```
exec('myprog > output.txt');
```

From memory, I believe there is a control character that you can prepend (like you do with @) to the `exec` family of commands that also prevents execution from pausing - can't remember what it is though.

**Edit** Found it! On unix, programs executed with & prepended will run in the background. Sorry, doesn't help you much.

Comment: I ended up using the batch file and doing:
system("cmd /c C:[path to file]");

That keeps the script going. Any ideas on how to kill the process? This actually opens up Adobe Reader, and I still need a way to close it before the script runs again.

Comment: Nevermind, turns out I don't need to kill the process. I can leave it running.

Comment: I'm currently trying this on a windows system and it is still waiting for the script to end in the browser window regardless of the fact it is outputting into a file. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @WilliamW W if you will refresh this window a new instance will be created and this may be problematic for some of us

Answer (score 1):

On my Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 machines, the only solution that worked reliably within pclose/popen was to invoke powershell's Start-Process command, as in:

```
pclose(popen('powershell.exe "Start-Process foo.bat -WindowStyle Hidden"','r'));
```

Or more verbosely if you want to supply arguments and redirect outputs:

```
pclose(popen('powershell.exe "Start-Process foo.bat 
             -ArgumentList \'bar\',\'bat\' 
             -WindowStyle Hidden
             -RedirectStandardOutput \'.\\console.out\' 
             -RedirectStandardError \'.\\console.err\'"','r'));
```