# exec PHP stucks loading

Tags: php

i'm developing a PHP APP and i need run a external program from a form, i know i need use EXEC function, but my exec function its not working, i check the antivirus and firewall and there is not bloking, this my code, its supposes work but not for me.

```
var_dump(exec('cmd.exe /K notepad.exe'));
```

this just keeps the chrome loading forever, i try diferents versions of this code and even format my pc, but nothing its working, pls help

sorry for my english, i speak spanish

Comment: Just tried it, your exact code worked for me.  It opened notepad is ther another issue?

Comment: just that, chrome stucks loading, im using WAMP on chrome, i check php.ini and exec its not blocked

Comment: now shows this error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

I'd try giving `popen()` a go, like so:

```php
var_dump(popen('notepad','r'));
```

Comment: Same, chrome stuck loading forerever.

Comment: It looks like using popen on windows will still wait for the child program to exit: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php#92413

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is PHP won't stop executing until it's sub-processes have quit. Notepad.exe won't quit until you manually close it so php will never stop running until it times out.

If you are trying to launch the program into the background on Windows so that PHP won't wait for it you can use the Windows `start /b` command

```
exec("start /b notepad");
```

Here is another question that may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10898943/2666293