# How to start cmd with php or other language on local server

Tags: php, shell, sass, cmd

I have a GUI with php, html, css, js and this site is on a local server.

I would like when I click on a button to open a cmd on the local server to open a cmd and launch a command.

I have already succeeded in doing it but the problem is that the command I want to use is `sass --watch` and as I said before the cmd does not launch.

I can already do an

```
$output = shell_exec('dir');
echo $output;
```

which is already good news, however, do

```
shell_exec('sass --watch ... ...')
```

do not work

Comment: In the title it says "on remote server", in the question it says "on local server". Make up your mind. Obviously though, PHP will launch the command on whichever machine it's being executed on, regardless of whether you've badged that as "local" or "remote" conceptually.

Comment: `do not work`...doesn't work how, exactly? If you put that sass command into the same style as your first snippet, what output do you get?

Comment: Why would you need to run `sass --watch` on a remote server to begin with? Are you doing _development_ on that machine?

Comment: I think the command works but it does not stay open

Comment: What's your evidence for this? And what exactly did you expect to happen instead? Your description is quite vague. And please reply to my question...if you run your command `$output = shell_exec('sass....');
echo $output;`, what do you see as the output? What did you expect instead?

Comment: when i echo this returns nothing

Comment: i expect the sass --watch start on my local server and stay on watch :)

Comment: I need to run sass --watch on my local server for don't use app like prepros

Comment: I suggest firing it in a separate command window maybe, using a technique like in the answer below. Then it can run a long-running process, and PHP doesn't have to wait for it to complete.

Comment: allright so i do $output = shell_exec('start cmd.exe @cmd /k "sass --watch blabla blabla"'); and my browser loads endlessly

Comment: yes try that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692263/running-a-php-exec-in-the-background-on-windows might also be relevant, possibly. Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067900/php-on-a-windows-machine-start-process-in-background . Or [any of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+run+shell+command+in+background+windows)

Comment: Ok I'll take a look and let you know if it works :)

Comment: ok suddenly I saw nothing works but a new track is actually starting shell_exec('start cmd.exe @cmd /k "sass --watch blabla blabla"');

I can see the cmd in the task manager of the local server

But I think the sass --watch command does not launch and therefore remains looped on it

There is no way to see the cmd in full screen?

Answer (score 1):

With the use of php you can do on Windows.

```
shell_exec('start cmd.exe @cmd /k "ping google.com"');
```

Comment: I know commands like this work but using sass --watch is the cause of this question :)